# How to obtain the string é by using the \detokenize command?

Tags: detokenize

I failed to use "\include" with a file that contain the string "é" in its name like "réserve". so I tried the following without success

> \include{\detokenize{réserve}}

After some trials I have noted that the command

> \detokenize{é}

produces "Ãľ" in place of "é".

Hence the question "How to obtain the string "é" by using the \detokenize command".

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
  \detokenize{é}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: It's much safer not to use special characters in file names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better using file names without special characters. If you like to live dangerously, you can patch some kernel macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\include}
 {\@include#1}
 {\expandafter\@include\detokenize{#1}}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\@include}
 {\string\@input{#1.aux}}
 {\string\@input{\string\detokenize{\detokenize{#1}}.aux}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\include{réservé}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the further visitors who, like me, comes from `google:// detokenize unicode`.

`\detokenize` is not UTF8-friendly, but sometimes you can replace it with the following command:

```latex
\newcommand{\utffriendlydetokenize}[1]{%
\scantokens{%
\catcode`\_=12%
\catcode`\^=12%
\catcode`\{=12%
\catcode`\}=12%
\catcode`\&=12%
\catcode`\$=12%
\catcode`\#=12%
\catcode`\~=12%
\catcode`\\=12%
#1%
}%
}
```

(source: https://gitlab.com/Nickkolok/biblatex2bibitem/-/blob/master/biblatex2bibitem.sty)

However, it does not work with `\include`.